# Jquery animation/function help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my first serious website and i'm stuck on this problem.

First of all I think my JQuery is extremly clumsy and could probably have been done in a more efficient way, would love some help on how to code this better (Feks i probably use to many functions). 
Secoundly I need some help with the animation. I want the divs to animate over to the leftside off the container before they open. The way it is now looks so unnatural.

I would appreciate any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/Skaadel/nt8a29gm/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="test1 col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks1">About Me</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test2 col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks2">Portfolio</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test3 col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks3">Project</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test4 col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks4">TEST</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
}
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
.container {
    background-color: black!important;
    margin-bottom: 40px!important;
}
#boks1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
}
#boks2 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#boks3 {
    height: 400px;
     width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}
#boks4 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boks1").click(function () {
        if ($("#boks1").width() == 100) {
            $("#boks1").animate({
                width: "720px"
            });
            $("#boks2").css("display", "none");
            $("#boks3").css("display", "none");
            $("#boks4").css("display", "none");

        } else {
            $("#boks1").animate({
                width: "100px"
            });
             $("#boks2").css("display", "");
            $("#boks3").css("display", "");
            $("#boks4").css("display", "");



        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boks2").click(function () {
        if ($("#boks2").width() == 100) {
            $("#boks2").animate({
                width: "720px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "none");
            $(".test4").css("display", "none");
            $(".test3").css("display", "none");

        } else {
            $("#boks2").animate({
                width: "100px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "");
            $(".test4").css("display", "");
            $(".test3").css("display", "");



        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boks3").click(function () {
        if ($("#boks3").width() == 100) {
            $("#boks3").animate({
                width: "720px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "none");
            $(".test2").css("display", "none");
            $(".test4").css("display", "none");

        } else {
            $("#boks3").animate({
                width: "100px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "");
            $(".test2").css("display", "");
            $(".test4").css("display", "");

        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boks4").click(function () {
        if ($("#boks4").width() == 100) {
            $("#boks4").animate({
                width: "720px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "none");
            $(".test2").css("display", "none");
            $(".test3").css("display", "none");

        } else {
            $("#boks4").animate({
                width: "100px"
            });
            $(".test1").css("display", "");
            $(".test2").css("display", "");
            $(".test3").css("display", "");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: looks fine to me except you should use a single document.ready() function, no need to make a seperate one every listener. What do you mean by the animation looks unnatural?

Comment: I jumps to the left when opening. If you open the div with "Portfolio" for example, it jumps to the left and opens. I would like it to slide over to the left and then open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code somewhat. Changes are as follows:

**1)** In your HTML **added class name boks** `class="boks"` along your inner `Div`.

**2)** In your CSS added properties for **`.boks`**, **`#boks1-2-3-4`** **and `.col-sm-3`**. Also **Added class `.zindex`**

**3)** In your JQuery i changed everything. Have a look and ask if you stuck anywhere.

[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/nt8a29gm/8/)

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".boks").click(function() {
        var curId = this.id; //Gives you id of clicked element.
        var curWidth = $("#" + curId).width(); // Taking width to check if it's 100px.
        var offset = $("#" + curId).offset(); // Taking Position for animating to left.
        var leftPos = offset.left;
        var firstElementLeftPos = $("#boks1").offset().left;
        leftPos = leftPos - firstElementLeftPos;
        if (curWidth == 100) {
          $(this).parent(".col-sm-3").css('left', '-' + leftPos + 'px');
          $("#" + curId).css("width", "720px").addClass('zindex');
        } else {
          $(this).parent(".col-sm-3").css('left', '0px');
          $("#" + curId).css("width", "100px").delay(500).queue(function() {
            $("#" + curId).removeClass('zindex');
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  width: 100%;
}
#test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 500px;
}
.container {
  background-color: black!important;
  margin-bottom: 40px!important;
}
/* Edits are to Below CSS */

.boks {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#boks1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#boks2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#boks3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
#boks4 {
  background-color: pink;
}
.col-sm-3 {
  left: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}
.zindex {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="test1 col-sm-3">
      <div class="boks" id="boks1">About Me</div>
    </div>
    <div class="test2 col-sm-3">
      <div class="boks" id="boks2">Portfolio</div>
    </div>
    <div class="test3 col-sm-3">
      <div class="boks" id="boks3">Project</div>
    </div>
    <div class="test4 col-sm-3">
      <div class="boks" id="boks4">TEST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! This is perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

just to show you how you could reduce your code with using `$(this)` and `class names` in jQuery ...

http://jsfiddle.net/nt8a29gm/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box").click(function () {        // check for click on .box
        if($(this).width() == 100) {     // if this one width is 100
            $('.box').not(this).hide();  // hide all but this
            $(this).animate({            // animate the one we clicked on
                width: "720px"
            });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({            // make this one small again
                width: "100px"
            }, 900, function() {         // 900 is animation speed
                // Animation complete.   // wait this animation is finished
                $('.box').not(this).show(); // show all boxes again
            });
        }

    });
});
```

HTML see `class="box"`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="test1 col-sm-3">
            <div class="box">About Me</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test2 col-sm-3">
            <div class="box">Portfolio</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="box">Project</div>
        </div>
        <div class="test4 col-sm-3">
            <div class="box">TEST</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, the code looks much better now. But I need to remove the col-sm-3 divs for it to open to the left each time, or else the divs will open from each col-sm. You can try open the 2th-4th div in your example and see what happens.

Comment: @HåkonSkaadel you mean you just want to hide those boxes and not remove them so it's no vertical change ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best to explain in english.
Hopefully this help http://imgur.com/oADNEne

Comment: @HåkonSkaadel I know, after I did it I've seen there is a problem with the left. You could try something with `$(this).parent('div').position().left` and not `offset()`  but I don't have time and the power of will to debug those kind of things for you